# how to properly use {% include %} tag to render a template (like partials) in django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of links on the left side that display my subcategories. What I want to happen is when a user clicks on a subcategory, it will render data/content to the right.

I'm using class based views, so my initial page is a ListView (subcategory_list.html) that displays all the Subcategory objects.

So each Subcategory object has a DetailView (subcategory_detail.html).

I want to display the DetailView template (on the same page) based on which Subcategory link was clicked.

If I'm understanding correctly, I will have to use {% include %} tag and some AJAX???

How would I stop the browser from going to the new URL??

Thanks!

views.py

```
class SubcategoryListView(ListView):
model = Subcategory
template_name = 'categories/subcategory_list.html'

class SubcategoryDetailView(DetailView):
model = Subcategory
template_name = 'categories/subcategory_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SubcategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['tasks'] = Task.objects.filter(subcategory=self.object)
    context['contractors'] = ContractorProfile.objects.filter(subcategory=self.object)
    return context
```

subcategory_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {% for subcategory in object_list %}
            <p><a href="{% url 'categories:subcategory' subcategory.id %}">{{ subcategory.title }}</a></p>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {% include 'categories/subcategory_detail.html' %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

subcategory_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h3>Subcategory: {{ object.title }}</h3>

    {% if user.is_authenticated%}
        <div class="row">
            {% for task in tasks %}
            <div class="thumbnail col-md-3">
                <img src="#" class="img-circle" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>Title: {{ task.title }}</p>
                    <p>Description: {{ task.description }}</p>
                    <p>Special Instructions: {{ task.special_instructions }}</p>
                    <p>Posted by: {{ task.user.username }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% cycle '' '' '' '</div><div class="row">' %}
            {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
    </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Contractors Available:</h3>
    <div class="row">
        {% for contractor in contractors %}
        <div class="thumbnail col-md-3">
            <img src="#" class="img-circle" />
            <div class="caption">
                <p>Name: {{ contractor.contractor.username }}</p>
                <p>Rating: {{ contractor.rating }}</p>
                {% if contractor.contractor.is_online == True %}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> <span>Online Now</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% cycle '' '' '' '</div><div class="row">' %}
        {% endfor %}
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^subcategories/$', views.SubcategoryListView.as_view(), name='subcategories'),
    url(r'^subcategories/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.SubcategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='subcategory'),
]
```

Comment: there is no possible way to do this without JavaScript or reloading the page. If you want the first solution, you should provide code describing what you've tried so far: you can't expect anyone to code an entire JavaScript behavior for you.

Comment: not looking for entire code.
just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Yes. 

So I can set it up where all links get an #id, and then pass a unique data-attribute through. Then append the {% include 'template_name.html' %} tag to a specific <div>.

But my concern/question is how will the system differ between  which DetailView to load (ie. Subcategory1 vs. Subcategory2 DetailView)?

Comment: My answer only cover the JS aspect of it. That is responsibility of Django: let me update the answer to cover also this concern.

Comment: Actually, this should not be a concern. self.object should already contain the Subcategory object. Try to open "youwebsite/subcategories/0" (considering you have at least one Subcategory object in the db). Does it render the correct one? If yes, your last concern is already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything which is not done by refreshing the page but requires server content, requires the use of JavaScript. In this case, you want to inject HTML content (given by Django) into your page.

I'm gonna use jQuery here.

First of all, you want to identify the div where the content needs to be injected (for JavaScript to be able to refer to it) and the div.

Also, remove the `{% include %}` tag (OR let the tag render what you want rendered when the user load the page).

(in `subcategory_list.html` (which should be renamed `subcategory.html`)):

```
<div class="container subcategory_list">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {% for subcategory in object_list %}
            <p><a href="{% url 'categories:subcategory' subcategory.id %}">{{ subcategory.title }}</a></p>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="subcategory_detail">
        {% include 'categories/subcategory_detail.html' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you need to tell the `a href` to not load the page but let an ajax call happen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { // shortcut for onDocumentReady

        // When you click an "a" tag who is child of an item with class "subcategory_list"…
        $('.subcategory_list>a').click(function() {

            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            // Use this if you want to add a loading gif or something similar
            // $('#subcategory_detail').html(my_cool_loading_gif_html)

            $.get(href, {
                success: function(response) {
                    // If the ajax call is successful, take the response and inject in div with id "subcategory_detail"
                    $('#subcategory_detail').html(response)
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    // Handle ajax errors here
                }
            })
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm..it's just taking me to the subcategory detail page even with 'return false;' at the end

Comment: the code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/Saturnix/w7L821vo/3/ have you checked your JS console? Have you tried debugging with console.log()? Is jQuery correctly included?

Comment: ok. return false is working now. i'm able to get the "href" value in the $.get{success:}.
but the "response" = undefined.
that means it's not actually getting the data from specific urls, correct?

Comment: am i going to have to serialize the data into JSON?

Comment: definitely not: you should get back HTML code, not JSON. I don't understand why the response object is empty though. Can you put a console.log(response) in the success function and see what you get?

Comment: undefined. but it's also hitting the errors...
it'll spit out "undefined" and then "errors" ( i console.log this part).
i also tried with the whole url, http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/subcategories/1

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/categories/subcategories/1 should be 127.0.0.1:8000/subcategories/1 according to your urls.py (but this might now be the problem). What do you mean by "it's also hitting the errors"? Is it calling the error function? Or is it calling the success function?

Comment: the URL is fine (/categories/subcategories/1). The main urls.py has a url(r'^categories/', include('apps.categories.urls')). That's why it has the beginning '/categories'. It is hitting both the success function, and the error function. I put two different console.log(). 1 in the 'success', and 1 in the 'error'. When I click the link, both spit out in the inspect element console.

Comment: oh, I forgot a comma after the closing parenthesis of the success function.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for walking it through with me Saturnix. I'll post the jQuery.